# stacking divs -- mix of vertical and horizontal layout

Tags: html, css

I would like to accomplish a mix of horizontal and vertical layouts.

```
<div>
  <div>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>B</span>
    <span>C</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>D</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**#1** It should look like this

```
A  B  C
<- D ->
```

**#2** Instead I have the two div elements next to one another

```
A  B  C  <- D ->
```

---

The real example has some very bad CSS that I recommend you not look at.  I wanted to set the top three items to the same width of **25px** and to be arranged next to one another.  And a picture beneath the two control buttons.

For some reason, the `div` elements are not stacking on top of one another and instead sitting next to each other all in one row.  Please help!

```
<div>
<div>
   <button style="width: 25px; float: left;">-</button>
   <span   style="width: 25px; float: left; text-align: center;">0</span>
   <button style="width: 25px; float: left;">+</button>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="starry-night.jpg" width="500">
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Give a width to the parent div.

Comment: here is my lame solution https://jsfiddle.net/pn7eyaz4/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <span>A</span>
    <span>B</span>
    <span>C</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span>D</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  width: 100%;
}

div > div {
  display: flex;           /* pertinent */
  width: 100%;
}

div > div > span {
  width: 33%;              /* pertinent */
  justify-content: center; /* pertinent */
  margin: 1px auto;        /* pertinent */

  background: #333;
  text-align:center;
  color:#efefef;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/16dqk7cL/1/

Comment: not necessarily `width: 33%` since the top row is only 75px but the image is 500px.  This is really great with the `div > div > span` selector

Comment: about the specific widths, that's up to you to apply for your particular scenario. cheers bud ...

Answer (score 0):

Give a width of 75 px to the parent div so that after placing 3, 25px elements the next element will be forced to be on the new line.

```html
        <div style="width: 75px;">
        <div>
           <button style="width: 25px; float: left;">-</button>
           <span   style="width: 25px; float: left; text-align: center;">0</span>
           <button style="width: 25px; float: left;">+</button>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="starry-night.jpg" width="500">
        </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions is to have a container Div and specify a width for it. Then adjust your other Divs width based on it.

```
<div style="width: 300px">
<div style="width=100%;">
   <button style="width: 33%; float: left;">-</button>
   <span   style="width: 33%; float: left; text-align: center;">0</span>
   <button style="width: 33%; float: left;">+</button>
</div>
<div style="width: 150px; margin:auto">
  <img src="starry-night.jpg" style="width: 150px;">
</div>
</div>
```